# Line with 1px height rendered with 2px height

Tags: html, css

I generated a lot of simple DIV lines going one by one with 1px height and different widths which changing in JS. But for some reason many line has 2px height. After changing height to 2px different lines has height equal 3px.

This problem reproducing in all common browser and in any browser zooms.

```css
.item_volume {
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_volume" style="width:10px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:20px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:30px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:40px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:50px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:60px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:70px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:80px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:90px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:100px"></div>
<div class="item_volume" style="width:110px"></div>
```

Comment: Have you taken into account browser defaults, or padding on html or body?

Comment: I tried. It doesn't help

Comment: optical illusion maybe

Comment: Seems to work fine above, have you tried resetting zoom?

Answer (score 0):

I found issue. Browser zoom was setted to 100%, but windows preferences screen size was 150%

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
.item_volume {
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```